# NoReverseMatch: 'app_name' is not a registered namespace [django-watson]

Tags: python, django-watson

- Django : 1.11
- Python : 3.5.x
- DB : SQLite

Hi there

I'm pretty sure I already following [the instruction](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki#getting-started-with-django-watson), but still no luck. When I run `./manage.py buildwatson` it's error :

```
# ./manage.py buildwatson

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 77, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'app_trip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/management/commands/buildwatson.py", line 142, in handle
    refreshed_model_count += rebuild_index_for_model(model, engine_slug, verbosity)
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/management/commands/buildwatson.py", line 61, in rebuild_index_for_model
    _bulk_save_search_entries(iter_search_entries())
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/search.py", line 205, in _bulk_save_search_entries
    search_entry_batch = list(islice(search_entries, 0, batch_size))
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/management/commands/buildwatson.py", line 40, in iter_search_entries
    for search_entry in search_engine_._update_obj_index_iter(obj):
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/search.py", line 484, in _update_obj_index_iter
    "url": adapter.get_url(obj),
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/watson/search.py", line 153, in get_url
    return obj.get_absolute_url()
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 58, in inner
    return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3])
  File "/home/zea/Riset/Python/env_vakansea/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'app_trip' is not a registered namespace
```

---

I have an app called `app_trip` and models called `Trip`, and here is my codes:

```
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig
from watson import search as watson

class AppTripConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_trip'
    def ready(self):
        Trip = self.get_model('Trip')
        watson.register(Trip)
```

---

```
# __init__.py

default_app_config = 'app_trip.apps.AppTripConfig'
```

---

I'm stuck. I opened an issue on their github, but still no response. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you